# redirect url to phar archive

Tags: php, stub, phar

I have created an archive file for my web app with script below :

```
   <?php
$phar = new Phar('appdepot.phar', 0, 'appdepot.phar');
$phar->buildFromIterator(
    new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__).'/depot0/', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)),
    dirname(__FILE__).'/depot0');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub("index.php"));
```

and I run my phar file through  :

```
    <?php

include("appdepot.phar")

?>
```

the index page is loaded and is redirect to login page but I have not found error

> > Not Found
>
> The requested URL /depot/login/login_id.php was not found on this
>   server.

how can I redirect all urls inside web app to phar (I think this is the work of stub file??)